# How to show multiple font list in Android and change text according to that fonts?

Tags: android, fonts, font-face

I want to show a list of fonts to the user and change the textview's text according according to the selected font. For that I need to access all the font family available and show them in spinner and when user selects a particular font then the textview's font will get change. How to provide font list to the user in Android? Please provide suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the font names to the spinner.

```
Spinner fname = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.fname_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        fname.setAdapter(adapter);
        fname.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
```

where `R.array.fname_array` holds the font list. And also you must put the ttf(font) file to the assets folder for using external font into your application.

```
public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {
            TextView ptext=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                View view, int pos, long id) {
                Integer idpos;
                idpos=pos;
                if(idpos==0)
                {
                    Typeface font1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"Molot.otf"); 

                    ptext.setTypeface(font1);   


                }

                if(idpos==1)
                {
                    //Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "The Font name is " +
                            //parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Typeface font1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"MTCORSVA.TTF"); 
                    ptext.setTypeface(font1);                   

                }
                if(idpos==2)
                {
                    Typeface font1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"TIMES.TTF"); 

                    ptext.setTypeface(font1);   
                } 

                ptext.setText(text.getText().toString());
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
              // Do nothing.
            }        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Android, the built in choices for fonts are:

- Droid Sans
- Droid Sans Mono
- Droid Serif

You can load custom fonts by copying the .ttf file(s) and placing it in assets folder. To load the custom font, create a object of Typeface and set it to the views.

```
Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/arial.ttf");
txtyour.setTypeface(type);
```